# git clone from linux to a windows with git-upload-pack not found. Msysgit prepend "windows path" to git-upload-pack

Tags: git, redhat, msysgit

Everything is in the title.

I'm pushing from a Windows XP with MSysGit installed.
I'm pushing on a Linux (RHEL 5) which doesn't have git installed in /usr or in /usr/local (no admin right on the box)

When I'm doing a :

```
git clone user@redhatbox:~/repo/myrepo.git
```

It failed because of git-upload-pack not found. So I use my super skills to read the manpage and add

```
git clone -u "/path/on/the/redhat/to/git-upload-pack" user@redhatbox:~/repo/myrepo.git
```

And what I get is :

```
ksh: line 1: D:/users/myuser/softs/Git/path/on/the/redhat/to/git-upload-pack: not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This %*$$~@ prepend a windows path to my path that should be the one on the redhat.

Oh yeah, we use ksh :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that MSysGit recognized a "unix path" in my command and prepend windows path in it, even if it has nothing to do with it.
The way to avoid that behaviour :

```
git clone -u "\/path/on/the/redhat/to/git-upload-pack" user@redhatbox:~/repo/myrepo.git
```

Yes, put a `\` before the first `/` in the path. MSysGit won't interpret it and won't prepend some windows path before. You need to put the path in `"` too.